# File access synchronization with flock in php

Tags: php, file, flock

I am trying to understand the right way to synchronize file read/write using the flock in PHP.

I have two php scripts.

testread.php:

```
<?
$fp=fopen("test.txt","r");
if (!flock($fp,LOCK_SH))
  echo "failed to lock\n";
else
  echo "lock ok\n";
while(true) sleep(1000);

?>
```

and testwrite.php:

```
<?
$fp=fopen("test.txt","w");
if (flock($fp,LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB))
{
  echo "acquired write lock\n";
}
else
{
  echo "failed to acquire write lock\n";
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Now I run testread.php and let it hang there. Then I run testwrite.php in another session. As expected, flock failed in testwrite.php. However, the content of the file test.txt is cleared when testwrite.php exits. The fact is, fopen always succeeds even if the file has been locked in another process. If the file is opened with "w" mode, the file content will be erased regardless of the lock. So what is the point of flock here? It doesn't really protect anything.

Comment: flock requires a file handle which has to be returned by fopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `fopen()` with the `w` mode in `testwrite.php`. When using the `w` option `fopen()` will truncate the file after opening it. (see [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)).

Because of that the file gets truncated in your example before you try to obtain the exclusive lock. However you'll need an open file descriptor in order to use `flock()`.

The way out of this dilemma is to use a lock file different from the file you are working on. The [`flock()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) manual page mentions this:

> Because flock() requires a file pointer, you may have to use a special lock file to protect access to a file that you intend to truncate by opening it in write mode (with a "w" or "w+" argument to fopen()).

Comment: You can't possibly put flock before fopen. If you don't use fopen to acquire a valid file pointer first, $fp is not even a valid value. How can you use flock on a null value?

Comment: @StephenCheng Of course!! How could I overlook this?!.. I need to be AFK a while but would help tomorrow...

Comment: That's what I suspected from the beginning. I did miss the note line on the documentation page. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is overly complicated. You can simply open the file using a "c" argument, which doesn't truncate the file. Then call ftruncate() only if you acquire the lock.

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php):

> 'c'   Open the file for writing only. If the file does not exist, it is
>   created. If it exists, it is neither truncated (as opposed to 'w'),
>   nor the call to this function fails (as is the case with 'x'). The
>   file pointer is positioned on the beginning of the file. This may be
>   useful if it's desired to get an advisory lock (see flock()) before
>   attempting to modify the file, as using 'w' could truncate the file
>   before the lock was obtained (if truncation is desired, ftruncate()
>   can be used after the lock is requested).